# W3C validation error 'document type does not allow element "link" here'

Tags: html, smarty, w3c, w3c-validation

I am using two files for displaying my webpage one is for header and footer(layout.htm) and the content(content.htm) using smarty I am including the file
Eg:
layout.htm

```
<html> 
   <head> 
      //here i am adding script and styles its common for all page 
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="body">
      {include file=$INNER_PAGE}        
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i need to include styles in inner page separately that style should be only for that page alone so I can't add that into layout.htm. So I am including the below line into my content.htm file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prop_descr.css"/>
```

because of that its showing error So how i can solve this

thank you!

Comment: I assume this is a template of some kind? Can you add a placeholder in to the `<head>` of the document for later-defined stylesheets?

Comment: how? So each and every script and style i want to add placeholder?

Comment: Your template does not allow to add `link` elements to the correct place.

Comment: @Athi: that's up to you; I'm not familiar with the templating system you're using.

Comment: ok let me try anyway thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a conditional inside the head tag in your layout.htm template:

```
{if $extra_css}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$extra_css}"/>
{/if}
```

and then assign the filename in your php to the variable:

```
$smarty->assign('extra_css', 'prop_descr.css');
```

**Edit:** if you need to use more than one, use an array and loop through it:

php:

```
$smarty->assign('extra_css', array('prop_descr.css','another.css','another_one.css'));
```

smarty:

```
{foreach from=$extra_css item=css_path}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$css_path}"/>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: more than 2 css and script also i want to add. So for all .css and .js i want to create a smarty variable?

Answer (score 0):

By HTML specifications, you cannot use a `link` element inside the `body` element. You should arrange things so that `link` elements appear inside the `head` element. In the given context, you can achieve this by omitting the `div class=body` markup (it should not be needed, though omitting it may require changes to your CSS code) as well as the `</head>` and `<body>` tags. There are probably smarter ways to achieve the goal, though.